# In Ansible, Credentials were rejected for Computers Attached to Active Directory

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ansible, kerberos

I have three 3 Windows computers. One is Windows server 2012, Other two are Windows 7 Desktop. Through Ansible I can individually manage all 3 windows machine through their local login account. Ansible Work Perfectly.

Now I configure AD in windows server 2012 and I joined two desktop computer to AD. Through Active Directory's Administrator Account I can login through all 3 Windows Machines.

To Manage AD Account in ansible I installed keberos as mentioned in [this documentaion.](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#installing-python-kerberos-dependencies)

My Configurations are as follow:

**/etc/krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]

default_realm = NAANAL.IN

[realms]

NAANAL.IN = {
    kdc = WIN2012.naanal.in
    default_domain = naanal.in
}

[domain_realm]

.naanal.in = NAANAL.IN

[login]

krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false
```

**Connection and Ticket Details:**

```
kinit Administrator@NAANAL.IN
Password for Administrator@NAANAL.IN:



klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: Administrator@NAANAL.IN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-07-10T20:41:25  2016-07-11T06:41:25  krbtgt/NAANAL.IN@NAANAL.IN
    renew until 2016-07-11T20:40:33
```

Now I just try to ping my all windows machines through
the account `Administrator@NAANAL.IN`

Here is my Configuration and output :

**hosts**

```
[windows]
192.168.1.13  -> Windows 7 Desktop Attached to AD
192.168.1.23  -> Windows 7 Desktop Attached to AD
172.30.64.77  -> Windows 2012 with AD
```

**group_vars/windows.yaml**

```
ansible_user: Administrator@NAANAL.IN
ansible_password: p@ssw0rd1
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

While I run `ansible windows -i hosts -m win_ping`

```
192.168.1.13 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "ssl: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
"unreachable": true
}
192.168.1.23 | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "ssl: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
"unreachable": true
}
172.30.64.77 | SUCCESS => {
"changed": false,
"ping": "pong"
}
```

i.e In Ansible, I can't login into computers attached to AD through AD user account. Where I miss things ?

Note:
I enabled Remote Connections in Desktops. Also tried with firewall disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed these two lines in your /etc/krb5.conf:

```
krb4_convert = true
krb4_get_tickets = false
```

They are in effect is telling the the Kerberos conversion daemon to get V4 tickets and then telling it not to accept v4 tickets. Apart from the contradiction in the code, Active Directory in all of its versions has only ever used Kerberos v5.  Remove these lines from your krb5.ini.

Reference: https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.4/krb5-1.4.1/doc/krb5-admin/login.html